# CSS Business Catalyst Dropdown Menu Not Hiding

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, business-catalyst

Really weird glitch. I have a CSS menu, which when the user hovers over the one link with a submenu, shows the submenu. If you're on any other page, then the menu will disappear when you mouse out of the containing element. However if you're actually on the page (Services) then it stays visible even after mousing out.

Super weird. I can't even inspect the element. I don't want to use Javascript either to hide it. Thoughts?

http://firstglancesolutions.kinetixbizsuite.com/services.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error below is given on the service page:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null

```
var _anchors = document.getElementById(menuid).getElementsByTagName('a');
```

The above line (from Java_DynMenusSelectedCSS.js) is looking for an id of menuid, but I could not find such an id in the services page html.

Line 216 of all.css:

```
#nav .drop-li ul.drop {
position: absolute;
top: 13%;
padding: 0 4px 7px;
clear: both;
z-index: 1000;
margin-top: 50px; }
```

I've removed `display:none;` and it now behaves as it should. Also you had overflow: none!important; which is not a valid property, use `hidden;` instead if you still want to use overflow.

Comment: I was getting the same issue before, but not anymore. Are you getting it on your end?

Comment: No I don't get that message now either. Check the answer now, I've just edited it.